# Usage of variable and role in openstack-ansible

Tags: ansible, openstack

I am a newbie to Ansible and I started to study deploying Openstack with Ansible recently.

Here is the git of openstack-ansible:

https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible

From the tutorial:

https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/newton/run-playbooks.html

there is one command running playbook:

```
openstack-ansible setup-hosts.yml
```

I read this playbook, it includes another playbook at line 16:

```
include: openstack-hosts-setup.yml
```

Then I read the included **openstack-hosts-setup.yml** and following is the snippet from it:

```
- name: Basic host setup
  hosts: "{{ openstack_host_group|default('hosts') }}"
  gather_facts: "{{ gather_facts | default(True) }}"
  max_fail_percentage: 20
  user: root
  pre_tasks:
   - name: Check for a supported Operating System
     assert:
      that:
        - (ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release == 'xenial') or
          (ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '7')
      msg: "The only supported platforms for this release are Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial) and CentOS 7 (WIP)"
  roles:
   - role: "openstack_hosts"
  tags:
   - openstack-hosts
```

I was confused about roles here

```
roles:
   - role: "openstack_hosts"
```

As far as I know, there should be directory structure when using roles like:

```
roles/
   openstack_hosts/
     files/
     templates/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     vars/
     defaults/
     meta/
```

However, I can't find this structure in this openstack-ansible project.
So I have no idea where is the role(openstack_hosts) in this playbook.

When running this playbook , an error occurred just expected:

ERROR! the role 'openstack_hosts' was not found in /opt/openstack-ansible/playbooks/roles:/root/ansible/roles:/opt/openstack-ansible/playbooks

Also, I was wondering where the variablescome from:

```
hosts: "{{ openstack_host_group|default('hosts') }}"
```

I thought the variable will be found from the directory ***vars*** or ***defaults***
under roles directory.
Since there is no such directory, I have no idea where this variable comes from.

Could any tell me where should I find the variable ***openstack_host_group***
and explain how the role is used here?
Or did I miss something or I was wrong with some concepts about Ansible?

Thanks!!

By the way, this is the first time I ask question.
If the question is not clear enough or something not proper, please let me know :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you didn't complete `bootstrap-ansible.sh` from [this guide](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/draft/deploymenthost.html). So you don't have required roles installed.

As for `openstack_host_group`, it seems that it is optional variable, so you can override default host pattern (which is `hosts`) if you want with extra variable (like `-e openstack_host_group=my_other_group`).

Comment: Thanks! I found the reason. The `bootstrap-ansible.sh` terminates due to some reasons and `ansible-galaxy` is not executed.

Comment: I manually executed `ansible-galaxy install --role-file=ansible-role-requirements.yml --force` and the roles required were installed successfully.

Comment: Since I am not familiar  with ansible-galaxy, trying to figure out how it works, I  accessed `https://git.openstack.org/openstack/openstack-ansible-openstack_hosts` which is from the config file ansible-role-requirements.yml from the browser , just wondering what inside the git repo.

However, I got 404 error.
Could you tell me how come the roles be installed successfully if the URL is not available?

Comment: Sorry to have so many question. Really appreciate for your help~ thanks a lot.

Comment: Git client works different than your browser, you can test git url with `curl -A "git/2.0.0" https://git.openstack.org/openstack/openstack-ansible-openstack_hosts/info/refs` or access it via [different url](https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/openstack-ansible-openstack_hosts/) in browser.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I probably understand. Thank you for your explanation. It helps me a lot!!